# Minecraft: copy structures between worlds not working on PS4 Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to copy structures between worlds on my PS4 Edition of Minecraft. However, when I save structures either in memory or to disk, I am unable to load them into another world on the same system. Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "PS4 Java Edition of Minecraft". Minecraft for PS4 and Minecraft Java Edition and two different versions.

Comment: Ok you’re right. Maybe this is not Java. It says Minecraft on the home screen. V 1.14.60

Comment: I assume this is Bedrock :)

Comment: Any ideasssss guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a PS4 Java edition, if you are playing on PS4 you're playing Bedrock edition. Currently the structure blocks on bedrock do not have the full functionality of Java and there is no way to transfer those structure file to another world without the help of third party tools. You would have to convert your world save and transfer it to a computer where you use a program called McEdit, download the Unified verision this will save you a step (converting your world to Java). With McEdit you will be able to copy structures.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response :) I am new to PS4 bedrock recently switching from PC Java. I am finding the differences between consoles/versions and certain mechanics of the games very interesting!

Comment: Nice answer, but do someone practice it? How to transfer to PC to use with that software????